# Getting c# input from console but does not return correct output

Tags: c#, input

C# program trying to get input from user and use those two numbers to find the product.

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static int computeProd1(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return (num1 * num2);
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int first, second;

            Console.Write ("enter first number: ");
            first = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write ("enter 2nd number: ");
            second = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

            int product = computeProd1 (first, second);
            //Console.WriteLine ("\n First number is: {0}" , first);
            //Console.WriteLine ("\n Second number is: {0}" , second);
            Console.WriteLine ("\nTheir product is: {0}" , product);
            Console.ReadKey ();     
        }
    }
}
```

First and second number output a number already no matter what i put.

Comment: So what is the issue, do you want to not accept non non numeric input?

Comment: just to accept numeric input

Comment: if i input 0 it will print 48 and any number thats greater than 0 it will add 48 to it

Comment: int.TryParse() is what you want.

Comment: the problem is you are using Read() instead of ReadLine()

Comment: didn't see that one but thanks

Comment: quick question when i blank out the console.write for both enter number i get an error is there anyway around this?

Comment: For debug by yourself, after any `first = Console.Read();` or `first = Console.ReadLine();` try to Write it on console by `Console.WriteLine(first);`

Comment: Send error message to clear the issue.

Comment: question to anyone...

Comment: I just started learning c# but should all functions be placed underneath the main class or does order not matter?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this code.

UPDATE

More fail proof way by using int.tryParse().

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int computeProd1(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return (num1 * num2);

        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            try
            {
                int first, second, product = 0;

                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out first))
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out second))
                    {
                        product = computeProd1(first, second);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Restart();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Restart();
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Their product is:\t" + product);

                Console.ReadLine();// So it wont close.
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static void Restart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oops something went wrong thats not a number!");
            Console.WriteLine("Restarting in 3 seconds...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var fileName =   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an exception error

Comment: input string was not not in correct format

Comment: Updated my answer, I would recommend the example s-s has given though. Many ways lead to rome some better then others.

Answer (score 1):

the console.Read return the ascii code of the char that was entered not the int value

try this code it will ask for to numbers (only numbers) and then return the product:

```
class Program
{
    static int computeProd1(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return (num1 * num2);

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int? first = null, second = null;
        int first_i = 0, second_i = 0;

        while (!first.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter first number");

            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out first_i))
            {
                first = first_i;
            }
        }

        while (!second.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter second number");

            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out second_i))
            {
                second = first_i;
            }
        }

        int product = computeProd1(first_i, second_i);
        Console.WriteLine("Their product is:\t" + product);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default [Console.Read()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the value of the input character based on the current [character encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example, here's link for [windows-1250](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table), it might explain why you get 48 for 0, etc.

If you want to work with single digits only, you can get the actual key value using [Convert.ToChar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tochar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For multi-digit values, you can use the [int.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Here's an example for both:

```
int first, second;
//for single digit inputs
var singleDigitInput1 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read).ToString();
var singleDigitInput2 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read).ToString();

//for multi digit inputs
var multiDigitInput1 = Console.ReadLine();
var multiDigitInput2 = Console.ReadLine()

if (int.TryParse(singleDigitInput1, out first) && int.TryParse(singleDigitInput2, out second))
{
    int product = computeProd1(first, second);
    Console.WriteLine("Their product is:\t" + product);
}
else
{
    //input cannot be converted to int
}
```

Comment: Well, probably not ASCII, but the idea is the same. See [Input.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.inputencoding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TomBlodget thanks for pointing it out, I'll remove that reference